# dumping rsyslogd output to some file

Tags: c, linux, rsyslog

I wish to dump the output of rsyslog(service) to some file at a selected
location.
Following is what I have tried :
1. Made changes to /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
#################
#### MODULES ####
#################
$ModLoad imfile

$ModLoad omprog   <----- NEWLY ADDED ------>

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat   

$ActionOMProgBinary /home/test/dmsg <----- NEWLY ADDED ------>  

# Filter duplicated messages
```

dmsg : Is a C program that reads the lines from stdin and writes it to
      file (/home/test/log_syslog_file)

I am expecting the output to be dumped to /home/test/log_syslog_file
But nothing happens.

code for dmsg (dmsg.c) ::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(){
char* lineptr;
size_t size = 0;   
int fd = open("log_syslog_file", O_CREAT| O_WRONLY);
        while(getline(&lineptr, &size, stdin)>0){
                if(write(fd, lineptr, strlen(lineptr))<0){
                        fprintf(stderr, "write failure");
                        break;
                }
        }
        free(lineptr);
        close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

-------- EDIT ---------
After starting the rsyslog service,
I am giving the following command:

```
rsyslogd -c5 -d -n
```

When I use the following it works fine :

```
cat /var/log/syslog | ./dmsg
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least one major bug in your code:

```
char* lineptr;
...
while(getline(&lineptr, &size, stdin)>0)
```

You never allocate memory for the string stored in `*lineptr`, but you don't tell `getline()` to allocate the memory for you, either.  The resulting buffer overflow can result in all sorts of exciting bugs showing up before the inevitable crash (for example, in my test run, `log_syslog_file` got the permissions `---x--x--T`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all what @Mark said. Apart from that make sure that 
you have  something like

```
*.* :omprog:
```

in your rsyslog.conf.
This will redirect all the messages to your program.

Comment: Should I add exactly this statement? Can you given an example ?

Comment: if you want *ALL* messages use the \*.\* part. for the syntax:
http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/omprog.html